# Accessing a nested JSON object to read into a table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, jsx

I have a [JSON object](https://pastebin.com/raw/gxpmDGLY) which I'm trying to parse into a table using React, however I'm having trouble using `.map()` to try to create a row for every unique combination of course code, `name`, `transferable_credits`, `transferable_credits -> institution`, `transferable_credits -> name`, and `url`. I can't seem to figure out how to get the key-values of the nested arrays within each JSON root key-value pair.

My React component so far:

```
import data from './data.json'

const Home = () => {

    return ( 
        <div className="home">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course Code</th>
                        <th>Vendor Institution</th>
                        <th>Vendor Course</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                {Object.keys(data).map(function(key, index) {
                    return (
                        <tr key={index}>
                            <td>{key}</td>
                            {Object.keys(data[key].transferable_credits).forEach(function(key2) {
                                return (
                                    <td>{key2.institution}</td>
                                )
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )})

                }
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

     );
}
 
export default Home;
```

Comment: _"I have a JSON object..."_ - No, you have not, because [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data[key].transferable_credits is a list so you should loop using map not Object.keys. Try this

```
import data from './data.json'

const Home = () => {

    return ( 
        <div className="home">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course Code</th>
                        <th>Vendor Institution</th>
                        <th>Vendor Course</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                {Object.keys(data).map(function(key, index) {
                    return (
                        <tr key={index}>
                            <td>{key}</td>
                            {data[key].transferable_credits.map(function(key2) {
                                return (
                                    <td>{key2.institution}</td>
                                )
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )})

                }
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

     );
}
 
export default Home;
```